# io.jsonwebtoken.io.DecodingException: Illegal base64url character: ' '

Tags: jwt, base64url

I am implementing signup, signin and logout function.

signup, signin is working. but, there is a problem in working logout.

here are my codes.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final RedisDao redisDao;


    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity signup(@Valid SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        String account = signUpRequest.getAccount();
        String password = passwordEncoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword());

        Optional<User> findAccount = userRepository.findByAccount(account);
        if (findAccount.isPresent()) {
            throw new CustomException(ExceptionStatus.DUPLICATED_ACCOUNT);
        }

        User user = signUpRequest.toEntity(Role.ROLE_USER, password);

        userRepository.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("회원가입 성공");
    }


    @Cacheable(cacheNames = CacheNames.LOGIN_USER, key = "'login'+ #p0.getAccount()", unless = "#result==null")
    @Transactional
    public UserResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        String account = loginRequest.getAccount();
        String password = loginRequest.getPassword();

        User user = userRepository.findByAccount(account).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException(ExceptionStatus.WRONG_ACCOUNT));

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            throw new CustomException(ExceptionStatus.WRONG_PASSWORD);
        }

        return new UserResponse().of(user);
    }


    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = CacheNames.USER_BY_ACCOUNT, key = "'login' + #p1")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity logout(String accessToken, String account) {

        Long expiration = jwtProvider.getExpiration(accessToken);
        redisDao.setBlackList(accessToken, "logout", expiration);

        if (redisDao.hasKey(account)) {
            redisDao.deleteRefreshToken(account);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("이미 로그아웃한 유저입니다.");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("로그아웃 완료");
    }


    public UserResponse getUser(String account) throws Exception {
        User user = userRepository.findByAccount(account).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("계정을 찾을 수 없습니다."));
        return UserResponse.of(user);
    }

    //
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtProvider {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_KEY = "auth";

    private static final long ACCESS_TOKEN_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 30L;
    private static final long REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7L;

    @Value("${jwt.secret.key}")
    private String secretKey; 
    private Key signature; 

    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private final RedisDao redisDao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey); 
        signature = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(bytes); 
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
    }

    private String createToken(String account, Role role, Long tokenExpireTime) {
        Date date = new Date();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .claim(AUTHORIZATION_KEY, role)
                .setSubject(account)
                .setIssuedAt(date)
                .setExpiration(new Date(date.getTime() + tokenExpireTime))
                .signWith(signature, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    
    public TokenResponse createTokenByLogin(String account, Role role) {
        String accessToken = createToken(account, role, ACCESS_TOKEN_TIME);
        String refreshToken = createToken(account, role, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME);

        redisDao.setRefreshToken(account, refreshToken, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME); 

        return new TokenResponse(accessToken, refreshToken);
    }

    
    public TokenResponse reissueAtk(String account, Role role, String inputRefreshToken) {
        if (!redisDao.getRefreshToken(account).equals(inputRefreshToken)) {
            throw new CustomException(ExceptionStatus.AUTHENTICATION);
        }
        String accessToken = createToken(account, role, ACCESS_TOKEN_TIME);
        String refreshToken = createToken(account, role, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME);

        redisDao.setRefreshToken(account, refreshToken, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME);

        return new TokenResponse(accessToken, refreshToken);
    }

    public Claims getClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(signature).build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            if (!token.substring(0, "BEARER ".length()).equalsIgnoreCase("BEARER ")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                token = token.split(" ")[1].trim();
            }

            Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(signature).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (SecurityException | MalformedJwtException | UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            log.info("만료된 jwt 토큰 입니다.");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.info("잘못된 JWT 토큰 입니다.");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Long getExpiration(String accessToken) {
        Date expiration = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(signature).build()
                .parseClaimsJws(accessToken)
                .getBody()
                .getExpiration();

        long now = new Date().getTime();
        return (expiration.getTime() - now);
    }

    public Authentication createUserAuthentication(String account) {
        UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(account);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableScheduling
public class SecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final RedisDao redisDao;

    private final CustomAccessDeniedHandler customAccessDeniedHandler;
    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(c -> c.configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                    config.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
                    config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
                    return config;
                }))

                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))

                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                                authorizeRequests
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers("/signup", "/login").permitAll()
//                                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
//                                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                                        .anyRequest().denyAll()
                )
                
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(redisDao, jwtProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
                        .accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler)
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization");
    }
}
```

I put access token in bearer token correctly. So it worked when I request "/login" POST

but when I request "/logout" DELETE it doesn't work!

[image]

showing accessToken fully, here it is.

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdXRoIjoiUk9MRV9VU0VSIiwic3ViIjoiYWFhYWEiLCJpYXQiOjE3MDU3NjMzMzYsImV4cCI6MTcwNTc2NTEzNn0.jKteJHNlcNU4Sh5EU1U6-ZaMhy6isFSaWtDiiJW63VE

[image]

here is error message

```
2024-01-21T00:17:29.664+09:00 ERROR 7822 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

io.jsonwebtoken.io.DecodingException: Illegal base64url character: ' '
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64.ctoi(Base64.java:221) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64.decodeFast(Base64.java:270) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64Decoder.decode(Base64Decoder.java:36) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64Decoder.decode(Base64Decoder.java:23) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.ExceptionPropagatingDecoder.decode(ExceptionPropagatingDecoder.java:36) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:309) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:550) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:610) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at kmu.likelion.webpage.user.jwt.JwtProvider.getClaimsFromToken(JwtProvider.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at kmu.likelion.webpage.user.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
```

I think there is not whitespace(' ') in accessToken.

But why application can't encode accessToken?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it's maybe in your `getExpiration` method, you’re directly parsing the `accessToken` without splitting it. If the `accessToken` you’re passing to this method includes the `Bearer`  prefix, this could be the source of the problem. The `Bearer`  prefix is not part of the JWT token and should be removed before parsing the token.

how about this?

```
public Long getExpiration(String accessToken) {
    // Remove the "Bearer " prefix if it exists
    if (accessToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        accessToken = accessToken.substring(7);
    }

    Date expiration = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(signature).build()
            .parseClaimsJws(accessToken)
            .getBody()
            .getExpiration();

    long now = new Date().getTime();
    return (expiration.getTime() - now);
}
```